# Convert String Expression into boolean expression

Tags: java, string, boolean

```
class A{

    public static void main(String a[]){
        String ad ="1<2";
        Boolean b = Boolean.parseBoolean(ad);
        if(b){
            System.out.println("true"); 
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping the output would be true but it actually prints false.

Comment: You are trying to evaluate "1<2" as a boolean - i.e. maybe "true" and "false" or "1" and "0" (I'm unsure what java's implementation does). parseBoolean won't try to parse and execute an expression.

Comment: You need to use some java expression language interpreter to do this. That function only converts a text to true/false, like Integer.parseInt will do with a number.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to confuse how `Boolean.parseBoolean` works. The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean-java.lang.String-) clearly states that:

> The boolean returned represents the value true if the string argument
>   is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true".

I.e. only expressions like `Boolean.parseBoolean("True")` or `Boolean.parseBoolean("tRuE")` return true, there is no argument evaluation done like for example in Javascript's `eval()` (although [you can use the ScriptEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java) in Java).

See [this example](http://ideone.com/7MhSj3):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String ad ="1<2";
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
    Object result = engine.eval(ad);
    System.out.println(Boolean.TRUE.equals(result)); // true
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you gave exact solution which i want.

Answer (score -1):

### Here we go:

```
class A{

public static void main(String a[]){
    String ad ="1<2";
    String tmpDataArray[] = ad.split("<");
   int num1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tmpDataArray[0]));
   int num2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tmpDataArray[1]));

   // Boolean b = Boolean.parseBoolean(ad);
    if(num1<num2){
        System.out.println("true"); 
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
}}
```